# Highest common factors of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

> Let h be a hcf of $f, g \in K[x]$ Then there exists polynomials a and
>   b such that
>
> $h = af + bg$

Can anyone explain this theorem to me intuitively?

Comment: This is a result of the fact that h(x) is the greatest common divisor (or, as you've stated, highest common factor). For any field $K$, $K[x]$ is a Euclidean Domain, which gives us an algorithm for finding such an expression. I would suggest reading about the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. This form is also called Bezout's identity.

Comment: I suspect that $K$ is a field here. Then $K[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence a PID and the ideal $(f)+(g)$ can be written as $(h)$ for some $h\in K[x]$. Then $h\in (f)+(g)$ wich comes to $h=af+bg$ for elements $a,b\in K[x]$.

Comment: This is the Bezout identity for the gcd.  Do you know the corresponding proof for integers? Are you familiar with [ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29) in rings?

Answer (score 2):

Let $h$ be a nonzero polynomial of the form $af+bg$ with smallest possible degree.  If you divide either $f$ or $g$ by $h$ then the remainder is also of that form, and has lower degree, so it must be zero.

So $h$ is a common factor of $f$ and $g$.  But any common factor of $f$ and $g$ divides $h$, since $h$ is of the form $af+bg$.

Comment: You've deduced that the gcd $d\,$ divides $h$. You need to say more to conclude that $\,d = h.\ $

Comment: I've also got that $h$ is a common factor of $f$ and $g$, which makes it a divisor of the gcd $d$, no?

Comment: You argued that $h$ is a common divisor that is also divisible by any common divisor. You need to say a bit more to get the sought result. If you claim that your $h$ equals the OP's (the given gcd) then you need to prove that.

Comment: Perhaps we are working from slightly different definitions of gcd, or we disagree on the degree to which small steps must be spelled out, or on what properties of the gcd are assumed known.  If you are puzzled about how to finish this up, I'm happy to make my answer more clear.  But I would need to know your exact definition of gcd, and what properties of it are familiar to you.  On the other hand, if you are aware of some step that I've left out, feel free to post your proof of that step.

Comment: Please clarify how you propose to complete the proof (or why you think it is already complete). I know these matters like the back of my hand and even still I cannot infer *precisely* what you intend.

Comment: $h$ is a multiple of $d$.  What can you say about the degree of the polynomial $h/d$?

Comment: Ok, that's a step in the right direction. I'd also *explicitly* mention the (necessary) use of the fact that $d$ is a "greatest" common divisor. The key point is that *linearly* representable common divisors are *necessarily* divisibly greatest, so greatest in degree.